# Random code sequence being generated in my URL

Tags: c#, url

I've recently developed a web a pplication. Specifics arent necessary. My issue is that whenever i start up my project, it generates a random code sequence, just before the name of my page.

```
http://localhost:53655/_Beta_Webiste/(S(sbjvzcdbbugovmuzvdt25scm))/administrator.aspx
```

As you can see, it is this random piece here

```
(S(sbjvzcdbbugovmuzvdt25scm))
```

Now it always starts with an (S("Random code here")). Always starts with an S. Does anyone know what the issue is here, as it can lead to confusion with the customers. Also please not that if i even just type

```
http://localhost:53655/_Beta_Webiste/administrator.aspx
```

It will still generate that code. (It does this for all links, even when i hover over my Href's. Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks, i will give you kiss just now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not an issue.
Your website using "**`Cookieless`**" environment (specified in web.config).

You can find `<sessionState cookieless="true" />` in your web.config file. Just make it `false` or remove completely (default value is false).

You can get more details about it from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479315.aspx).